# Different @patch behavior between Python 2.7 and 3.6 (using mock)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mocking, patch

`@patch` does not seem to produce the same behavior under 2.7 and 3.6.

Here is my project structure:

```
project/
    foo.py
    bar.py
    lol.py
tests/
    test_project.py
```

foo.py:

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

bar.py (imports Foo):

```
from project.foo import Foo

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        f = Foo()
```

lol.py (imports Bar):

```
from bar import Bar

class Lol:
    def __init__(self):
        b = Bar()
```

Since `bar.py` imports Foo using `from project.foo import Foo`, I am patching `bar.Foo` (according to [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) docs):

test_bar.py:

```
from project import lol
from project import bar

@patch('bar.Foo')  # Works in 3.6, fails with 2.7
def test_lol(mock_Foo):
    l = lol.Lol()
    mock_Foo.assert_called()
```

This setup runs correctly in Python 3.6 but fails in 2.7 (Foo does not get patched).

However, if I switch my setup to:

test_bar.py:

```
from project import lol
# from project import bar # No need to import bar anymore

@patch('project.bar.Foo')  # Works in 2.7, fails with 3.6
def test_lol(mock_Foo):
    l = lol.Lol()
    mock_Foo.assert_called()
```

It works in 2.7 but fails in 3.6.

What is a recommended way to use `@patch` to make it produce results consistent between python versions?

Note: This problem only appears when I test `lol.py`. If I call `bar.py` from the unit test, I get consistent results using second setup `@patch('cookie_test.bar.Foo')` and it works in both 2.7 and 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate the difference using 2.7 vs 3.6 upon adding `__init__.py` files to your `project` directory, and changing the import of `Bar` in `lol.py`:

```
from project.bar import Bar
```

In either case, you should not need to import `bar` in your test - mock is taking care of finding `bar` by parsing the string passed to the `mock` decorator.

I suspect the error you're seeing is due to the fact that Python 3 uses absolute imports (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)